# provide service dynamically into component angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-components

I just want to provide service in Component dynamically by calling any function within the component. I have created a array and then pushed the array services in providers. I don't know this is the right way to do it or not. Thanks

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

let providers:any = [];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: `
    <p></p>
  `,
  styles: [],
  providers: [providers]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addProviders();
  }

  addProviders() {
    providers.push({provide: service1, useClass: UseClass1});
    providers.push({provide: service2, useValue: UseValue2});
  }

}
```

Comment: Not quite enough info here to craft an answer. You want to reuse a component that will have dynamic services? How dynamic? Why could you not attempt this in the module?

Answer (score 0):

Try add services in each `@NgModule` in `providers` section if you using separate NgModules

I tried it and working ....

I have multi  NgModule and import them in SharedModule ... so I providing the services I use in imported component

Comment: By adding services into modules makes it globally available which is I don't want.